# ResultSet.next() is false. Even though table is not empty

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I'm using Oracle 19c database. And HOMESQUAD_EMPLOYEE is table with columns : EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,EMP_MOBILE_NO,EMP_PASSWORD with VARCHAR2(50).

I'm trying to retrieve the row with given EMP_MOBILE_NO in Java using ResultSet object .
Connection is established successfully. PreparedStatement is getting executed successfully,ResultSet is not null but ResultSet.next() is null.

The same query is getting executed and I'm getting required row.
[image]

Here's the Code and its output.

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {

    //Loading Driver
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    //Loading Connection
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl", dbUsername, dbPassword);

    //Executing query;
    System.out.println("Connection Established");
    //Object to store result
    items = new ArrayList < Object > ();
    Map properties={ActionType=ProcessLogin, mobileNo=8308856606};
    queryString=buildLoginQuery(properties);
    System.out.println("Query: " + queryString);
    if (queryString != null && !queryString.trim().equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Into P Statement If Loop");
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(queryString);
        System.out.println("StateMent Prepared: " + pstmt.toString());
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("Query Executed");
        System.out.println("Result Set rs.next():" + rs.next()); //Error Point
        while (rs != null && rs.next()) {
            items.add(constructLoginProps(rs));
        }
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
        if (pstmt != null) {
            pstmt.close();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception Occured in aDBExecute:" + e.getMessage());
}

//constructLoginProps Function

private HomesquadEmployee constructLoginProps(ResultSet rs) {
    HomesquadEmployee vo = new HomesquadEmployee();
    try {
        if (rs.getString("EMP_PASSWORD") != null) {
            vo.setEmpPassword(rs.getString("EMP_PASSWORD"));
        }
        if (rs.getString("EMP_ID") != null) {
            vo.setEmpId(rs.getString("EMP_ID"));
        }
        if (rs.getString("EMP_NAME") != null) {
            vo.setEmpName(rs.getString("EMP_NAME"));
        }
        if (rs.getString("EMP_MOBILE_NO") != null) {
            vo.setEmpMobileNo(rs.getString("EMP_MOBILE_NO"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occured in buildLoginQuery: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return (vo);
}

//HomesquadEmployee Class
public class HomesquadEmployee {
    private String empId;
    private String empName;
    private String empMobileNo;
    private String empPassword;
    public HomesquadEmployee() {}
    public HomesquadEmployee(String empId, String empName, String empMobileNo, String empPassword) {
        this.empId = empId;
        this.empName = empName;
        this.empMobileNo = empMobileNo;
        this.empPassword = empPassword;
    }
    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public String getEmpMobileNo() {
        return empMobileNo;
    }
    public void setEmpMobileNo(String empMobileNo) {
        this.empMobileNo = empMobileNo;
    }
    public String getEmpPassword() {
        return empPassword;
    }
    public void setEmpPassword(String empPassword) {
        this.empPassword = empPassword;
    }
}


//build Query Function
private String buildLoginQuery(Map properties) throws Exception {
        String mobileNo="";
        String password="";
        queryString="SELECT * FROM HOMESQUAD_EMPLOYEE ";
        if(properties!=null && (String)properties.get("mobileNo")!=null) {
            mobileNo=((String)properties.get("mobileNo")).trim();
            queryString=queryString+" WHERE EMP_MOBILE_NO = "+"'"+mobileNo.toUpperCase()+"'";
        }
        return(queryString);
}
```

Output:

```
Connection Established.
Query: SELECT * FROM HOMESQUAD_EMPLOYEE  WHERE EMP_MOBILE_NO = '8308856606'
Into P Statement If Loop
StateMent Prepared: oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@514f51cf
Query Executed
Result Set rs.next():false
```

Please help me out.

Comment: The output does not match the code in your question.  Also ... what is the point if this code?  `if (queryString != null && !queryString.trim().equals("")) {`.  The query string is clearly neither null or an empty string.  This suggests to me that that the code you are running is different the code you have shown us ... and that's where the problem lies.

Comment: @StephenC Updated. Please check it now.

Comment: OK ... assuming that is now accurate ... the only thing I can think of is that you are querying a different database or a different server.  However, that is definitely the wrong way to use a prepared statement.  You shouldn't be using "string bashing" to assemble the query string.  You should have a fixed query string with a `?` marker in it, and use a `set` method call to provide the value.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Did you commit your data in SQL Developer? Are you sure it is the same database? That is almost always the cause of this type of 'data is missing' problems.

Comment: >System.out.println("Result Set rs.next():" + rs.next()); //Error Point< Are you sure? You then proceed to call `rs.next()` *again*, which would fail for only one row returned and you should find *that* is where the error is. In fact you shouldn't be assumptive about a call to `next()` not failing, since it *would* fail for no rows found

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkRotteveel  :) I got my problem solved

Comment: Thanks a lot @g00se  :) I got my problem solved. I didn't notice about rs.next() thanks for it

Comment: OK, that's good. Can you please post up how as the answer